# URL query in express js with postgresql

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, express

I am trying to make a query from my database through the url, but the response just returns all my persons.

```
exports.getPersonByName = async (req, res) => {
const query = req.query.q
try{
    const person = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM person WHERE firstname LIKE $1', [query])
    res.status(200).json(person)
} catch(error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that `console.log(query)` prints a non-empty string?

Comment: When I try to console.log it both before and in the try block, nothing appears in the console...

Comment: That is the reason because the query is returning all persons. You should make sure that your `q` query parameter is correctly passed and received.

Comment: In the router I have /person and in the url i type in /person?q=Tim. Is this wrong?

Comment: The request looks ok. Can you post your main Express application file? (app.js or index.js)

Comment: https://github.com/MadsNyl/Sandbox---postgreSQL Here are all the files

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your implementation.

1. You are missing the `urlencoded` middleware in the `server.js` file (Add it after the `app.use(express.json())` line):

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

2. You have not configured the route for the `getPersonByName` method in `person.route.js`.
   You don't need to specify query parameters in the route itself.
   Currently, your `GET /person` route is used by the `getAllPersons` function, so you have two options:

- Unify the `getAllPersons` and `getPersonByName` functions under the same path `GET /person` and retrieve the parameter if present.

You will be keeping only the `getAllPersons` route and functions and handle the `q` parameter in there

```
exports.getAllPersons = async (req, res) => {
  const query = req.query.q || '';
  try {
    const person = await pool.query(
      'SELECT * FROM person WHERE firstname LIKE $1',
      [query]
    );
    res.status(200).json(person);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

- Define a different route for the `getPersonByName`, for example:

```
router.get('/byname', controller.getPersonByName)
```

And send your requests to `/person/byname?q=Example` (Keeping the `getPersonByName` and `getAllPersons` methods as defined)